# What is the difference between Super thing = new Sub() and Sub thing = new Sub()?

Tags: subclass, superclass, super, subclassing, difference

```
Super thing = new Sub();
Sub thing = new Sub();
```

What is the difference in terms of accessing thing and what I can do with it etc?

Comment: what language is this?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the variabele `Super thing` can be reassigned to any other subclass that implements `Super`, whereas `Sub thing` of course can only be assigned to another `Sub` class.

That said, assigning `new Sub()` to `Super thing` uses **polymorphism** and **overriding**, of which you can find a good tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm). You can only call the methods defined in the class `Super`. If these methods are overridden (read: redefined) in one of the subclasses, polymorphism will make sure the overridden method is called, instead of the method in the class `Super`.